# Short Story Boy Looks Through Telescope, Sees Future Self

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, horror

A boy was in his bedroom and looked out through his telescope. He sees some kind of weird cloaked figure in the bell tower of a church and it freaks him out. The story goes on to follow the boy's life as he grows up etc etc. Eventually, he becomes a monk and one night he climbs up to the top of the church tower and he sees a boy watching him through a telescope.

The story was not sci-fi but it had a bit of a weird time-paradox type thing. The tone was more like a scary/weird story. I may have read it online. I read it somewhere around 2007/2008/2009 but the story could have been published at any time.

Comment: This reminds me of Mr. Tompkins series of physics texts for laypersons.